# Sorting a list of strings numerically

Tags: python

I have a list of strings with my filenames:

```
flist = ['0.png','10.png', '3.png', '4.png', '100.png']
flist.sort()
print(flist)
```

Output:

```
['0.png', '10.png', '100.png', '3.png', '4.png']
```

But I want:

```
['0.png', '3.png', '4.png', '10.png', '100.png']
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: Thank you for the hint but I think the solutions on this Thread are not simple enough. I know that I can start slicing around my filenames to achieve the goal but I was wondering if there is a SIMPLE way, such as bruno desthuilliers provided. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, but you should note that the answer given is entirely dependent on being able to use `split()` to isolate the numerical value. The duplicate works in a whole range of cases. The title of your question (should other people stumble across this in searches) belies the specific case you have.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by "without slicing the file name". What do you think `split()` _does_?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
flist.sort(key=lambda fname: int(fname.split('.')[0]))
```

Explanation: strings are lexically sorted so `"10"` comes before `"3"` (because `"1"` < `"3"`, so whatever comes after `"1"` in the first string is ignored). So we use `list.sort()`'s `key` argument which is a callback function that takes a list item and return the value to be used for ordering for this item - in your case, an integer built from the first part of the filename. This way the list is properly sorted on the numerical values.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do that like this:

```
flist = ['0.png','10.png', '3.png', '4.png', '100.png']
flist.sort(key=lambda x: '{0:0>8}'.format(x))
print(flist)
```