# sorting a list with alphanumeric characters as filenames within a subdirectory in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to work with files which needs to be used for downstream processing. 
The files in the subdirectory structure and the filenames are somewhat like :

- ./resources/json
  -pdfextract_1_pdf.json
  -pdfextract_4_pdf.json
  -pdfextract_3_pdf.json
  -pdfextract_2_pdf.json

When I just try to sort just the files in the subdirectort ./resources/json. It works.

```
mylist = ['pdfextract_2_pdf.json','pdfextract_3_pdf.json','pdfextract_1_pdf.json']
mylist.sort()
```

This one seems to be not working. Eventhough everything looks similar (just a string)

```
['pf1109__r_td6831__425_a_b_c.pdf.page33.pdf_testing_xml.json', 'pf1109__r_td6831__425_a_b_c.pdf.page4.pdf_testing_xml.json', 'pf1109__r_td6831__425_a_b_c.pdf.page41.pdf_testing_xml.json']
```

Comment: What do you mean by failed to work? Why are you mixing / and \ separators?

Comment: Works just fine in python 2.7 and python 3.5, 3.6

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. [I tried it on python 3.7](https://ideone.com/5XGVvp) and it works fine

Comment: @ArunAS, see the actual example (sorry, had to create a toy example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: From what I've understood, you say it's not working because page33 comes before page4 in your sort. I think this is what you're looking for [Sorting a list of strings numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737587/sorting-a-list-of-strings-numerically)

Answer (score 2):

`sorted()` works perfectly well in python3

```
>>> mylist = ['./resources/json\\pdfextract_2_pdf.json','./resources/json\\pdfextract_3_pdf.json','./resources/json\\pdfextract_1_pdf.json']
>>> print(sorted(mylist))
['./resources/json\\pdfextract_1_pdf.json', './resources/json\\pdfextract_2_pdf.json', './resources/json\\pdfextract_3_pdf.json']
```

Comment: I tried it with the below example. It doesnt seem to work. `['pf1109__r_td6831__425_a_b_c.pdf.page33.pdf_testing_xml.json', 'pf1109__r_td6831__425_a_b_c.pdf.page4.pdf_testing_xml.json', 'pf1109__r_td6831__425_a_b_c.pdf.page41.pdf_testing_xml.json']`

Comment: @Betafish You may want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-numerically

Answer (score 1):

for descending  order

```
sorted(mylist , reverse = True)
```

and for ascending order just use

```
sorted(mylist , reverse = false)
```

or

```
sorted(mylist)
```