# How to sort a dictionary by nested value?

Tags: python, json, sorting, dictionary, nested

I am storing stock data in a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "06/01/2021 18:41:02": {
    "NASDAQ-BYND": {
      "Sell": "6",
      "Neutral": "9",
      "Buy": "11"
    },
    "NYSE-CCL": {
      "Sell": "3",
      "Neutral": "8",
      "Buy": "15"
    },
    "NASDAQ-NVDA": {
      "Sell": "2",
      "Neutral": "8",
      "Buy": "16"
    },
    "NASDAQ-TQQQ": {
      "Sell": "2",
      "Neutral": "8",
      "Buy": "16"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to sort the dictionary by the **'Buy'** value so that my result looks like this:

```
{
    "NASDAQ-NVDA": {
      "Sell": "2",
      "Neutral": "8",
      "Buy": "16"
    },
    "NASDAQ-TQQQ": {
      "Sell": "2",
      "Neutral": "8",
      "Buy": "16"
    },
    "NYSE-CCL": {
      "Sell": "3",
      "Neutral": "8",
      "Buy": "15"
    },
    "NASDAQ-BYND": {
      "Sell": "6",
      "Neutral": "9",
      "Buy": "11"
    }
}
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
with open("/dayData.json", 'r') as day:
    data = json.load(day)
    keys = list(data)

print(sorted(data[keys[len(keys)-1]].items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['Buy'])
```

The reason I store the initial keys in the `keys` variable is because the original JSON file is quite large and I only want to get the data from the last dated entry. Calling `list(data)` only returns the initial parent keys which are all of the dates.
The result of running the code above:

```
{
  "NASDAQ-BYND": { "Sell": "6", "Neutral": "9", "Buy": "11" },
  "NYSE-CCL": { "Sell": "3", "Neutral": "8", "Buy": "15" },
  "NASDAQ-NVDA": { "Sell": "2", "Neutral": "8", "Buy": "16" },
  "NASDAQ-TQQQ": { "Sell": "2", "Neutral": "8", "Buy": "16" },
  "NYSE-AMC": { "Sell": "1", "Neutral": "9", "Buy": "16" },
  "NASDAQ-AMZN": { "Sell": "14", "Neutral": "10", "Buy": "2" },
  "NASDAQ-AAPL": { "Sell": "13", "Neutral": "10", "Buy": "3" },
  "NASDAQ-COIN": { "Sell": "7", "Neutral": "7", "Buy": "3" },
  "NASDAQ-MARA": { "Sell": "10", "Neutral": "9", "Buy": "7" },
  "NASDAQ-TSLA": { "Sell": "9", "Neutral": "8", "Buy": "9" }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or need to know?

Comment: But `"11"` is correctly sorted before `"15"`, `"16"`, and `"2"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a list of strings numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737587/sorting-a-list-of-strings-numerically)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I made a poor choice of what data to show and I am aware that the data is already organized in an ascending order, but I am trying to sort the stock keys ("NASDAQ-APPLE, NASDAQ-TSLA") by their "Buy" values in descending order. The other question you linked does not solve my problem as it refers to sorting a list not a nested dictionary.

Comment: I guess your question is why the result is sorted by the "Buy" values *alphabetically* and not *numerically*?

Comment: That you wanted to sort in descending order is new information. In that case also use `reverse=True` as argument to `sorted`, in addition to converting the "Buy" values to integers in the `key` function (alternatively, negate the resulting integers).

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I suppose that is the root question of what I want to know. Is that what is occuring in my code? Are the values of 'Buy' keys being sorted alphabetically and not _numerically?_ Thanks.

Comment: Yes they are, because they are strings. Convert them to integers using `int()`, as shown in the question I've linked.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ha that was it! I just needed to put`x[1]['Buy']` in an `int()` function. Can't believe I overlooked the fact that it was returning a str and not an int. Thanks.